# some convenience functions seem to be missing from gdb

Tags: gdb

I am using gdb version 7.5.1 on linux and was trying to use convenience functions like `$_memeq` only to find that it apparently isn't there:

`Undefined command: "$_memeq".  Try "help".`

when i type `help function` I get this output:

```
(gdb) help function
Placeholder command for showing help on convenience functions.

List of function subcommands:


Type "help function" followed by function subcommand name for full documentation.
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Command name abbreviations are allowed if unambiguous.
```

and even `apropos memeq` returns nothing. Why would this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From GDB 7.6 release [announcement](http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-announce/2013/msg00000.html):

> ** New Python-based convenience functions ($_memeq, $_streq,
>          $_strlen and $_regex)

I guess 7.5.1 is not fresh enough.